# sql error or missing database (no such table found) (SQlite Database connection from Java)

Tags: java, sqlite

I want to connect SQLite Database which is protected by password from Java. Below is the code snippet that I tried to connect with it but always giving error **(org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: Employees)**) Database Name: RightPunch.db. When I run the program, it always creates an empty database in the same location and giving the error. It works fine for without password protection database. What should I do or how can I connect password protected SQLite database?

```java
public class SQliteDbConnection {
    
    public static Connection connect() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {  
         
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    
        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:C:/ProgramData/BioPlugin/RightPunch.db;Version=3;Password=12345";
        
        Connection conn = null;  
      //  SQLiteConnection oConn = null;
        try {  
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            System.out.println("Connected with Database successfully");
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }  
        return conn;  
    }  
        
}
```

```java
            try {
                    
                    Connection oConn = SQliteDbConnection.connect();
                    
                    String sql = "SELECT * FROM Employees";
                
                    
                    Statement stmt = oConn.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                    
                
                    
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        System.out.println(
                                rs.getInt("EmployeeID") + "\t" + rs.getString("EmployeeName") + "\t" + rs.getDouble("ManagerID"));
                    } 
                

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Please explain more precisely what is working and what is not working. Do you have an existing database without password that your program is able to open? And you have an equal database with a password that has been set? Or ist your "RightPunch.db" empty what could result in an error that is pointing to a missing table "Employees"?

Comment: Hi NIklas, Yes I want to access the table named "Employees" of the existing Database "RightPunch.db". The database is password protected. I am unable to access the database because of the error I mentioned. But If I reset the password then I am able to access. So what are the changes required of the above code to access the "RightPunch.db" with password?

Comment: Hi @Niklas p Any suggestion?